# Is there a relationship between Turing's Halting theorem and Gödel Incompleteness

Tags: logic, category-theory, computability, incompleteness

Turing's proof that a Halting oracle is impossible and Gödel's proof that and omega-consistent first order theory of arithmetic must be incomplete are similar in that they use self-referential arguments. Is there an interesting relationship between them especially in light of the Curry-Howard Correspondence and especially the categorical version thereof i.e. the Curry-Howard-Lambek Correspondence.

Comment: Gödel's theorem is precisely that the set of theorems of arithmetic is a recursively enumerable set but not a recursive set. The halting theorem is precisely that the set of (turning machine, input) pairs that halt is a recursively enumerable set but not a recursive set.

Comment: @MJD, could the Curry Howard Correspondence be useful in any way though?

Comment: I don't know any way that the CH correspondence ties in, but I'm not at all an expert, and I think you should wait a while and see if you get any better answers than my little comment. I feel like I left out some important connections between Gödel's theorem and the halting problem, and mentioned only one similarity.

Comment: Related: [Prove Gödel's incompleteness theorem using halting problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53321/prove-g%C3%B6dels-incompleteness-theorem-using-halting-problem)

Comment: You can see Peter Smith, [An Introduction to Gödel's Theorems](https://books.google.it/books?id=-SBpYKebkJMC&pg=PA328) (2nd ed - 2013) : **Ch.43 Halting and incompleteness**, page 328-on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Turing's proof that a Halting oracle is impossible and Gödel's proof that and omega-consistent first order theory of arithmetic must be incomplete are similar in that they use self-referential arguments. Is there an interesting relationship between them.

Well, Gödel's theorem is a simple consequence of Turing's proof.

Take a look at my *Introduction to Gödel's Theorems*, for example. §43.2 (in the numbering of the second edition) shows that the recursive unsolvability of the halting problem implies that the set of truths of the first-order language of arithmetic is not recursively enumerable. But the theorems in that language of a formalized theory $T$ are recursively enumerable. So there are truths that $T$ can't prove, and if $T$ is sound, can't disprove either. So it is incomplete.

§43.3 then strengthens the result by dropping the assumption that $T$ is sound in favour of the assumption of omega-consistency, together with the usual assumption that $T$ is (primitive) recursively axiomatized and includes a small amount of arithmetic (e.g. contains Robinson arithmetic Q  -- the crucial thing is being strong enough to represent the (primitive) recursive functions). Then we can prove that $T$ is incomplete, going via the unsolvability of the Halting Problem (it's a half-page proof in detail, so forgive me for not reproducing it here)!